# An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread

Tags: android, nativescript

While running a nativescript app on Android I am getting the following error:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
JS: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
JS: Calling js method onItemClick failed
JS: 
JS: [object Object]
```

tns.html

```
<ListView [items]="abc$ | async" (itemTap)="onClickRoom($event.view.bindingContext)">
  <template let-item="item">
    <Label [text]="item"></Label>
  </template>
</ListView>
```

component.ts

```
onClickRoom(abc: string) {
this.date = new Date();
this.eventArray = appSettings.getString('itemsArray') || [];
this.eventArray.push(this.evntList);
appSettings.setString("itemsArray", JSON.stringify(this.eventArray));
}
```

It's running fine on iOS and it happens only on Android. How can I solve this issue? Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: A code snipped of the click handler and a little bit more context would allow us to actually help you.

Comment: ok. am including my html and component files.

Comment: I think you've not included onClickRoom's implementation.

Comment: included function name is onClickRoom